# SmartCard: unable to get ATR

Tags: smartcard

I am creating a smartcard reader. The MCU is STM32F469, interface device is TDA8035. When I insert the card, the VCC and IO pin have been pulled HIGH, the clock pulse has been also provided as the configuration, but I am not able to receive ATR through I/O pin. I've been struggling with this for several days. Please help me. I'm begginer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Without substantial additional details no specific answer will be possible.)

What I recognize from the little information above is, that you don't mention the *reset* signal, which has to be set to *low*. This is in fact the signal for the card to send the ATR. I recommend to make yourself familiar with ISO 7816 part 2 and 3 to avoid waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, I am still unable to receive any I/O signal, though I've already set Reset pin to High after 40000 CLK pulse.

Comment: I have some confusion about logic level of reset signal. according to ST guide, reset signal have to set to high after at least 40000 clk pulses, but several other document (include your recommend) recommend to pull it to low.

Comment: I realize that my card is memory card, using synchronous protocol. Unfortunately, my hardware as well as software are for processor card. With memory card, I can easily find it's devices, ex SLE4442... But I don't know any kinds of processor card. Could you please give me a name.